# Is there any advantage in using IdentityColum+AnotherColumn vs just IdentityColum as the Clustered Index?

Tags: sql-server, index, primary-key

The database where I work has Table A with column `A_id` (an autoincrement field, which in practice is always unique, never null), and column `Date` (not unique), and other columns.

For some reason, the primary key/clustered index of this Table is a composite of columns `A_id` + `Date`. I think this is stupid, but before talking to my boss, I'd like to be sure.

If I understand correctly, the index is a Binary tree using `A_id`, and at each leaf, there's another mini Binary Tree that uses `Date`, with the actual data at each of its leaves.

But since `A_id` is already unique+not_null, then each mini Binary tree is simply an arrow pointing to exactly one leaf, making that part of the index totally superfluous.

I can think absolutely no cases whatsoever where such a composite pk/index could have any benefits over simply using `A_id` as the pk/index. There's absolutey no query that could be faster using this index than using simply `A_id` index.

Additionally, using this composite pk brings possible errors -you could manually insert a row with a repeated `A_id`, if it has a different `Date`, which is horrible- and that means every JOIN needs to include `Date` as well, to prevent joining with the wrong row: `ON x.A_id=a.A_id AND x.Date=a.Date` which is just annoying.

Also I suspect this index confuses the Query Planner, requiring me to add hints like `OPTION (LOOP JOIN)`.

Am I correct to say that such composite PK/Clustered Index is **strictly worse** than a simple PK/Clustered Index using `A_id` alone?

Comment: I generally agree this is a bad primary key design from both normalization and query performance perspective. The use case where the composite clustered index key might benefit performance is the `Date` column will be implicitly included in all non-clustered indexes, which could allow non-clustered indexes to cover queries. Removing it without due diligence could result in performance regression of some queries.

Comment: `A_id` isn't guaranteed to be unique if `IDENTITY_INSERT` has been used or reseeding has happened. Have you validated that there are definitely no dupes?

Comment: The index isn't nested binary trees BTW - it is a single B tree with the whole key. All of the non leaf levels of the index will have rows of keys with two column (`A_id, Date` ) - but this will be unnecessarily bloated by having superfluous keys

Comment: @DanGuzman I didnt know about the possible benefit of covering non clusters, Ill have to learn more on that before advancing on this. #MartinSmith, no there are no dupes, for now

Answer (score 3):

> Am I correct to say that such composite PK/Clustered Index is strictly worse than a simple PK/Clustered Index using A_id alone?

There's really two questions here:

The first answer regarding having a composite primary key, is probably generally worse, since as you pointed out, breaks down the key's integrity and allows the same `A_id` to be specified more than once then. Now, if you're inheriting this data, as Martin Smith points out, the data may currently not be unique on `A_id` anyway (despite being an identity) and should be thoroughly checked prior to removal of the `Date` column.

Secondly, the primary key does **not** need to be the clustered index. So it is possible to define `A_id` as the primary key but subsequently have a composite clustered index on `(A_id, Date)` instead. The potential benefit that could have is by helping cover your nonclustered indexes (as mentioned by Dan Guzman), since every nonclustered index also stores the clustered index key. If some of your queries leverage some nonclustered indexes, and those queries reference the `Date` field, then your nonclustered index likely won't need to explicitly keep a copy of the `Date` (via it's definition) since it'll already have one via the clustered index key it stores.

Converse to that, it's typically best to keep the clustered index key as light as reasonably possible, since it is copied into every nonclustered index. If you have no need for the `Date` field in any of your nonclustered indexes, then this is just unnecessary bloat in them. When applicable, an int identity column typically makes for an excellent clustered index key by itself.

So to the original question:

> Is there any advantage in using IdentityColum+AnotherColumn vs just IdentityColum as the Clustered Index?

Yes, there can be, in regards to the clustered index key. It's not often the case though. Regarding the primary key, it makes less sense.

> Also I suspect this index confuses the Query Planner, requiring me to add hints like `OPTION (LOOP JOIN)`.

Less than likely, but no one can say without seeing the query itself and its execution plan. Having to use that kind of option is more of a red flag that your query needs tuning instead.